# Why is my nginx load balancer misdirect phpMyAdmin after login?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, load-balancing, apache-2.4

In my testing server, I have an nginx load balancer pointing to Apache server(s) running on the same machine, and I've installed phpMyadmin under Apache.

My nginx config:

```
http {
 upstream backend {
  ip_hash;
  server 127.0.0.1:8080 max_fails=3  fail_timeout=15s;
 }

 server {
  listen 80;
  location / {
   proxy_pass http://backend;
  }
 }
}
```

My Apache ports.conf is 8080 and I already have changed that at my VirtualHost conf.

The problem here is: when I open `http://127.0.0.1/phpMyAdmin` I get to the proper login page, however, once I inter my login details and click login I get forwarded to `http://backend:8080/phpmyadmin`. More interestingly is that the login request go successful because when I go back to `http://127.0.0.1/phpMyAdmin` I find myself already logged in.

My server is running a fresh ubuntu installation and everything uses default settings with no changes -apart from things above :).

Comment: Why are you running Apache here?

Comment: This is my testing server, my production servers are almost the same settings: 1 load balancer (nginx) and 4 servers (Apache).

Comment: Really? You're not seriously going to put phpMyAdmin in _production_?!?

Comment: @MichaelHampton is it too harmful to be used in production? :( Anyway, for my testing/developing server I guess it should be OK.

Comment: Try developing against something that you'd use in production. You'll find that the products you write will have fewer integration and deployment problems.

Comment: My production setting are the same as my developing/testing, my only problem is with phpMyAdmin in my testing. Thanks to @MichaelHampton I'm not going to use it now in production, but for the meantime I need it for developing/testing purposes. Much appreciate your comments, like it when a question brings more useful things ;)

Comment: I don't even use it in testing, I just use the mysql command line whenever I need to look at something in the database. Basic SQL is not hard to learn :)

Comment: @MichaelHampton appreciate your comment, but do you have any clue why I'm having this issue?

Comment: It turned out I'm not the only one having this issue, see: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/phpmyadmin/+bug/1334324 . Although guys here: http://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/bugs/4474/ have closed this issue as upgared requsted, upgrading does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://backend/;
}
```

The trailing slash will tell nginx to rewrite redirects from your backend to the normalized root URI, removing backend host and port and using configuration's primary server name.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others **phpMyAdmin should not be used in production**, but I'll answer my own question anyway.

To get this working I had only to specify my virtual host and server name for Apache:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
ServerName www.example.com
```